# shell_exec not returning anything PHP , Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, exec, shell-exec

today I started a project that will analyze tracks I have and add a BPM tag to each song inside of a mysql table. Everything was going well untill I was doing my finishing steps:
shell_exec-ing my command in ubuntu...

```
    $command='/usr/bin/bpm-tag -f -n "/var/www/website/music/music.mp3"';
    echo shell_exec($command);
```

This was my command/ code and it doesnt work...(it didnt output anything, when I run the same command using putty I get what I need...)

```
$output=  shell_exec('whoami');

print_r($output);
```

Outputs:

```
www-data
```

Comment: Observe that the user `www-data` may not have the rights to either run this command or modify the files envolved.

Comment: Also, `shell_exec()` will only return the program's `stdout`. Perhaps what you see in PuTTY is the program's `stderr`. Try using `$command = '/command ... 2>&1';`

Comment: oh thanks! 2>&1 this realy worked! what does 2>&1 do? I dont understand THANKS!!

Comment: It dumps `stderr` onto `stdout` so those applications that only read `stdout` receive `stderr` too the same way the console does.

Comment: Another way to do that is to use `proc_open()` that allows you to take separate descriptors for each "pipe".

Comment: ahaaa! I see, sorry for this awfull question/problem I had... :D
how would I have used proc_open()?

Comment: http://www.php.net/proc_open see the examples